# Android application being too laggy

Tags: android, http, android-asynctask

My Android application is running very slow and lagging much. I have PHP API on my server and my application requests data through HTTP.

Though, the problem is that sometimes I should wait for few seconds before I can see the result. I have all calculations done in the main thread in onCreate (parsing XML, adding controls) and downloading data from HTTP server in AsyncTask.

How to optimize my program to make it faster? I want it to load activity first and only then, in background, download and parse data. How is it possible? Sorry for newbieship.

Comment: You should parse your xmls in AsyncTask and then provide the data to your main UI

Comment: Please post your code ? Thanks

Comment: Without looking your code, how and what can we suggest for the optimization?

Answer (score 0):

what did you mean by lagging ? Will you elaborate more on the issue.

One suggestion that remove parsing XML from OnCreate and move it to AsysnTask. The reason for this is as you are doing time consuming operation in UI Main thread which will impact the activity to be shown.

Create thread to perform HTTP related operations and parse the response on the same thread and while doing the parsing operation show dialog.

Dismiss the dialog when parsing got completed and then show the activity which you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

In the `doInBackground()` method in AsyncTask add the data parsing and create the data objects then in `onPostExecute` update the ui elements.

The reason to do something like that is for the application to be responsive in all this time and just make small jobs on the ui thread so as not to freeze.

You can instatiate your views to a default state an add a progress somewhere on top to indicate that the activity is currently loading. For example you can create an empty `ListView` or a `Button` that cannot be selected and when the parsing is done then you should set the adapter to the list and make the button back to selectable again.

All this things can be implemented according to what you want the user to be able to do in the time of his waiting.